# nans and infs error in python for self-defined function that uses curve_fit()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan, curve-fitting

I am trying to find how to use a self-defined function to obtain high order moment like h3 moment of gauss-hermite function from arrays in python. I will explain my full setup of code to help you understand this problem better.

I am creating maps of statistics (like standard deviation, h3, h4 etc) of velocity values of galaxy simulations. I have a galaxy simulation snapshot with spatial 'x_new', 'y_new' values of the stars and velocity 'vz_new' values of the stars that occupy those spatial coordinates. I have divided the x-y plane of the galaxy into cells and then allowed the velocity values of the stars to fall into the corresponding cells. Then I usually just take the standard deviation using np.std(), which is an in-built numpy function, of the array of velocity values in every cell and plot a map using those numbers.

However for obtaining h3 or h4 values, I needed to obtain a spectrum from each cell of velocity values first, then define a Gauss-Hermite function, then obtain a curve fitting of the velocity values to that Gauss-Hermite function and then obtain h3 or h4 value from that curve fit. So, I tried to define my own function, get_h3(). This is the part where I am experiencing some "NAN" errors like:`ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs`
[image]
This is the relevant part of the code I am using. :

```
import pynbody
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import norm
import pylab as plb
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
# import plot lib
import seaborn as sns

#the galaxy spatial coordinates are stored in arrays x_new, y_new. The velocity values are stored in array v_new.


#laying a grid on the galaxy snapshot on an x-y plane
x_new = x_new // 2 + 20
y_new = y_new // 2 + 20
k=(40)
cells = [[[] for y_new in range(k)] for x_new in range(k)] #creating cells or pixels on x-y plane


#letting vz_new values to fall into the grid cells
for ycell in range(k):
    for xcell in range(k):
        cells[ycell][xcell] = vz_new[(y_new  == ycell) & (x_new  == xcell)]
          
for ycell in range(k):
     for xcell in range(k):
        this = cells[ycell][xcell]
      #print(ycell, xcell, len(this), this, sep='\t')
   


 #Define function to get h3 value from velocity arrays in every cell. This will involve nested functions. 
#We will take the velocity array and create a spectrum using plt.hist to get velocity values and corresponding frequencies.

def get_h3(dataV):
    counts, binz, bars = plt.hist(dataV, density=True, bins=150)
    x_h = binz[:-1]
    y_h = counts

    n = len(x_h)                            
    mean = sum(x_h * y_h) / n                   
    sigma = sum(y_h * (x_h - mean)**2) / n        

    
    # Let's define the Gauss-Hermite function
    #a=amplitude, x0=location of peak, sig=std dev, h3, h4
    def gh_func(x_h, a, x0, sig, h3, h4):
        return (
            a * np.exp(-0.5 * ( (x_h - x0) / sig )**2) *
            (
                1 +
                h3 * (
                    ((x_h - x0) / sig)**1 + (-np.sqrt(3)) +
                    ((x_h - x0) / sig)**3 * (2 / np.sqrt(3))
                ) +
                h4 * (
                    (np.sqrt(6) / 4) +
                    ((x_h - x0) / sig)**2 * (-np.sqrt(6)) +
                    ((x_h - x0) / sig)**4 * (np.sqrt(6) / 3)
                )
            )
        )

    popt, pcov = curve_fit(
        gh_func, x_h, y_h, 
        p0=( np.max(y_h), mean, sigma, 0, 0 ), maxfev=5000
    ) #i'm taking h3=0 and h4=0 as guesses
    return popt[3] #this popt[3] is our h3 value

####-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#getting h3 from velocity values in each cell-I THINK THIS IS WHERE THE MAIN ISSUE IS.
h3 = [[[] for y_new in range(k)] for x_new in range(k)]
#cells[ycell][xcell]=
for ycell in range(k):
    for xcell in range(k):
        #cells[ycell][xcell] = np.array(vz_new[(y_new == ycell) & (x_new == xcell)],dtype=object)
        cells[ycell][xcell] = vz_new[(y_new == ycell) & (x_new == xcell)]
        # QUESTION: is there a way to replace invalid nans or infs with 0 for this next part?
        h3[ycell][xcell] = get_h3(cells[ycell][xcell])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# heatmap
ax=sns.heatmap(h3, cmap='RdBu')
ax.invert_yaxis()
#plt.savefig('spec_heatmap_150bins_15deg_trial7.png')
plt.show()
```

Can someone help me understand how to handle these errors or define a function that could ignore nan and infs values? My experience with programming is not extensive, so apologies if anything is unclear. Let me know and I will further clarify. Thanks a lot.

Comment: the question is, how do you want to handle `NaN` in your ydata?   You can transform your lists to `np.array` and check for `NaN` with `np.isna` to filter away the bad data entirely before passing it to your curve fit function..

Comment: I tried to use np.nan_to_num(cells[ycell][xcell]) to replace nans and infs with 0 and big values  before passing to curve_fit() and it still gives the same error.

Comment: A few remarks. `get_h3()` only makes sense if  `dataV` has 5 or more entries. If this is not the case you can immediately return a default value, e.g. `nan`. Using the histogramm to get `mean` and `sig` is a bit wired. Just use `numpy.mean()` and `numpy.std()` on the initial data. Finally, I'd use a likelyhood method and skip the histogram part completely.

Comment: @mikuszefski, yes, I am getting nan values because cells[ycell][xcell] is a list of lists, some of which are empty or have fewer than 5 entries. What can I do for lists that do not have enough entries? Also, I used plt.hist() to generate a frequency spectrum for the list elements because that spectrum is the curve that I fit my gauss- hermite function to. What do you mean by likelihood method? Thanks!

Comment: Using histograms I guess you have a probability distribution. in such a case you can use [maximum likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) to get the parameters, avoiding binning errors. As for the errors. As I said. Just check for it. If there re not enough measurements to calc the parameters, don't do it.